# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la data vue3 desde un archivo de javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Accedo al metodo changeGenero con el import desde mi archivo JS, pero no reconoce la data, dice que **la propiedad no ha sido definida**.

```
export default {
    name: 'dashboard-app',
    data(){
           return {
             aspirante:{
                nombre: '',
            },
        }
      },
    methods: {
    changeGenero(val){
    console.log(this.aspirante);
     },
    }
}


import {createApp} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import App from '../../../vue/pages/dashboard/dashboard-bolsa-create.vue';
createApp(App).mount("#dashboard-bolsa");
App.methods.changeGenero(1);
```

> aspirante = undefined

Comment: El código debe ir en formato de texto por favor, recuerda que simpre puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608626/edit). ;)

Comment: Gracias, ya lo modifique